# Can a data set of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ decide if it is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, computational-science

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ whose explicit formula is unknown, but there is a very large data set $\{x_i\}$ such that each $f(x_i)$ is known. Can we tell whether $f$ is differentiable at $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

I know there are approximation algorithms/theorems to $\textit{calculate}$ the derivative at each point, given the data set. However, I'm only interested in deciding whether they are at least $C^1$.

Context: if I have a collection $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ of such functions, I have their inverses (in a proper domain). I want to check whether the transition functions $f_i\circ f_j^{-1}$ are diffeomorphisms on the overlaps, defining a n-dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Common practice in mathematics is to do this with pencil and paper, but I wonder if we can automatize it.

Comment: Two questions: do you already know that $f$ is continuous? Is the data set $\{x_i\}$ large but finite?

Comment: We can assume $f$ continuous (can we infer that from the data?). The data set is finite, I'm picturing a real life application.

Comment: Without more assumptions, you can hardly do anything: values of $f$ at points other than $x_i$ can be anything. It is possible for $f$ to be even everywhere discontinuous.

Comment: In "the real world" we collect data, assume some model that appears to fit the data, test the fit, and if we like the model can then differentiate the function based of the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question is tagged computational-science, I am assuming that the data set $\{x_i\}=\{x_1,\cdots,x_d\}$ is finite. If this is indeed the case, the answer is no. Even if $n=k=1$, we can always find, for example, a polynomial $p:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ so that $p(x_i)=f(x_i)$, and of course the polynomial is $C^1$. But We can also join each consecutive pair of points $(x_i,f(x_i))$, with a straight line to form a function that agrees with $p$ on every $x_i$, but which is not differentiable (unless all $(x_i,f(x_i))$ lie on a line). In fact, we could even build the function $$g(x)=p(x)+c(x)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_d),$$ where $c(x)$ is a nowhere-differentiable function. Then $g(x)$ is differentiable nowhere except possibly at each $x_i$.

From a purely mathematical standpoint, you cannot even infer that the function $f$ is continuous. Perhaps the function $f$ jumps to infinity quickly between $x_3$ and $x_4$ before becoming well-behaved again. Perhaps $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=1/\sqrt[5]{\pi}$. Perhaps $f$ is constant on each interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}),$ with jump discontinuities at the endpoints. All these examples are assuming $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, but the same types of behavior could also occur in higher dimensions.

Comment: So we have to take differentiability for granted, if we want that data set to describe such a function?

Comment: Yes. However, if you can assume that your function is continuous (usually, I think this is not a terrible assumption for real-life applications), then you know you can approximate that function as close as you like by a $C^1$, or even a $C^\infty$ function.